# Match specific text in array property value then replace and only output replaced values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to filter the following array by values.
The values including '-usd' need to be replaced without '-usd'.
After that I want to only output that replaced values! and not horse or mouse. How can I do this?

So the filtered array may look like:

```
arr = [
          {animal: 'cat', price: 150},
          {animal: 'dog', price: 350},
        ]
```

So far i made this:

```
arr = [
      {animal: 'cat-usd', price: 150},
      {animal: 'dog-usd', price: 350},
      {animal: 'horse', price: 5000},
      {animal: 'mouse', price: 50}
    ]


    var filter = arr.map((i, k) => {
      var ret = i.animal.replace(/-USD/gi, '')
      return ret;
    })

    console.log(filter)
```

[JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/naguleresu/edit?js,console,output)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can first filter the ones which have `-usd` in them and then use your map function

```
var filter = arr.filter(i => i.animal.indexOf('-usd') >= 0).map((i, k) => {
      var ret = i.animal.replace(/-USD/gi, '')
      return ret;
    })
```

Comment: replace that with .indexOf('-usd') >= 0

Answer (score 1):

Check for `i.animal.indexOf('-usd') !== -1` in your `filter` method.

```js
arr = [
  {animal: 'cat-usd', price: 150},
  {animal: 'dog-usd', price: 350},
  {animal: 'horse', price: 5000},
  {animal: 'mouse', price: 50}
];

var filter = arr.filter((i, k) => {
  if(i.animal.indexOf('-usd') !== -1){
    i.animal = i.animal.replace(/-USD/gi, '');
    return i;
  }
})

console.log(filter)
```